# Iterating an associative array with jQuery .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Probably the most contributing factor for this question is that I am extremely sleepy right now.

I have an array, which I initiate:

```
var cells = [];
```

Then i put some values in it (jQuery objects), for example:

```
$("td").each(function () {
  var td = $(this);
  cells[td.attr("id")] = td;
});
```

And now my problem. This code:

```
$(cells).each(function (i) {
  console.log(this) // firebug console
});
```

logs absolutelly nothing. When i changed the associative array to a normal, number index one by substituting

```
cells[td.attr("id")] = td;
```

with

```
cells.push(td);
```

It worked correctly.

Also, when I try to iterate with the for..in loop it works as expected.

```
for (var cell in cells) {
  console.log(cells[cell]);
}
```

Doeas that mean that jQuery's .each method does not accept associative arrays or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

JavaScript does not have associative arrays. It has Arrays and it has Objects, and arrays happen to be objects. When you do this:

```
var a = [];
a['foo'] = 'bar';
```

..you're actually doing the equivalent of this:

```
var a = [];
a.foo = 'bar';
// ^--- property of object 'a'
```

That is to say you're actually adding a *property* called `foo` to the *object* `a`, *not* adding an *element* to the *array* `a`.

From the documentation for [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> Arrays and array-like objects with a `length` property (such as a function's `arguments` object) are iterated by numeric index, from `0` to `length-1`. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

Since you created an `Array` (`[]`) jQuery looks at its `length` property, and since you have not added any elements to the array (only *properties* on the object, remember) its `length` is still zero and so jQuery (correctly) does nothing.

What you want to do instead, as others have noted, is create an Object using e.g. `var cells = {};`. Since a non-Array object has no `length` property (not by default, anyway) jQuery will know that you really want to iterate over its *properties* instead of numeric indices as in an Array.

Comment: All I needed to know, I guess I missed some lessons :).

Comment: Glad I could help. It is a little confusing, just because the square-bracket syntax does two completely different things on Array objects!

Comment: The [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function you linked above is *not* the same function used by the OP in his example.  He uses [$(cells).each(...)](http://api.jquery.com/each/), which is intended for use on jquery-sets of DOM elements, not on generic 'collections' (objects/arrays).  I'm not saying it won't work as-is, but a truly complete answer would point out the distinction - or at least link to the docs that match the function being used by the OP.  (Other than that though, good answer).

Answer (score 9):

You seem to be thinking Javascript's arrays are associative, which is not the case. You're probably looking for objects (or hashes) instead:

```
var cells = {};         // Not [].
$("td").each(function() {
    var td = $(this);
    cells[td.attr("id")] = td;
});

$.each(cells, function() {
    console.log(this);  // This should work as expected.
});
```

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but JavaScript doesn't have a data type called "hash." It has Objects, which happen to have an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals) syntax which looks a lot like hashes in other languages. `var cells = {};` merely creates an object with no properties (aside from those inherited from `Object.prototype`).

Comment: @Jordan, you're absolutely right, for some reason I thought that "hashes" was easier to understand than "objects" in our context. I updated my answer to use both terms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I accepted Jordan's because of his explanation of how my wrong assumptions affected the .each method.

Comment: @Przemek, no problem, you did well, his answer is very good :)

Answer (score 6):

use `$.each(cells, function(i) { ... })` instead of `$(cells).each(function...)`

The [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function is different from the [`$(selector).each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function.