# Displaying keys and values to all elements in an associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery, associative-array

I have an array, `clientList`:

```
[
  [
    clientID: "123"
    data: "data1"
  ]
  [
    clientID: "456"
    data: "data2"
  ]
  [
    clientID: "789"
    data: "data3"
  ]
]
```

I'm trying to iterate over all 3 arrays, displaying all keys and values for each.

I iterate over the individual arrays by doing the standard `$.each(clientList, function() {}`.

Now I'm trying to iterate over a single array using `$.each($(this), function(key, value) {}` but the key is just the index in number form, not the key name as a string.  Is there any way to do this?

I found [Iterating an associative array with jQuery .each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671727/iterating-an-associative-array-with-jquery-each) as a possible starting point, but there's no way to initialize `$(this)` to `{}`, is there?

Comment: You're missing a few commas... ;)

Comment: In the array?  It's a copy/paste out of chrome's debugger...

Comment: you can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(clientList))` to get the correct string representation of the object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are syntactical errors in your array, I hope that is a copy mistake if so then

```
var clientList = [{
    clientID: "123",
    data: "data1"
}, {
    clientID: "456",
    data: "data1"
}, {
    clientID: "789",
    data: "data1"
}]

$.each(clientList, function (idx, obj) {
    $.each(this, function(key, val){ //you can use `this` or `obj` to iterate over
        console.log(key, val)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A69f8/)

Inside the `each()` callback `this` refers to a javascript object, so you should not try to create a jQuery wrapper around it using `$(this)` while passing to the second `each()` call.

Comment: Ah, this and $(this) - finally.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

What's wrong with plain JavaScript?  You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to go through the keys and values on an object.

```
// Loops through every single client in the client list.
clientList.forEach(function (client) {
    // Logs each of the key-value pairs on the client object.
    Object.keys(client).forEach(function (key) {
      console.log(key + ': ' + client[key]);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for using vanilla js, jQuery is nice, but it's no substitute for understanding what jQuery is actually doing.

Comment: Object.keys is not supported in IE 11

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
var clientList = [
    {
        clientID: "123",
        data: "data1"
    },
    {
        clientID: "456",
        data: "data1"
    },
    {
        clientID: "789",
        data: "data1"
    }
];

$(document).ready(function(){
    var output = $('#output');
    $.each(clientList, function(index, obj){
        output.append('<div>Item ' + index + '</div>');
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){
             output.append('<div>' + key + ' = ' + value + '</div>');
        });
        output.append('<br />');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4JcjR/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print them out in a debugger try Object.entries(yourAssociativeArray)